# How can I change language but only for the terminal?

Tags: command-line, language-support, locale

How do I change the language of the terminal to English?

I am familiar with using `vi`.

If the terminal language is controlled by `etc/default/locale`, what am I supposed to change there?

```
LANG="el_GR.UTF-8"
LANGUAGE="el:en"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Answer (score 8):

#### Tl; dr

since you want to set everything to English (assuming that programs using GNU gettext should use Greek as a fallback language):

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en:el
```

Or if some `LC_*` variables are defined already in your shell's environment and you wish to override them:

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en:el
```

To make the settings stick, add the `export`s at the end of `~/.bashrc`.

---

Changing `/etc/default/locale` will affect the whole system's locale and consequently the locale of all users who didn't set a specific locale, so you shouldn't change it if you want to change only the language of the command running in your user's terminal / console.

The locale of the commands running in your user's terminal / console can be changed by exporting the following environment variables:

```
LANG
LANGUAGE
LC_ADDRESS
LC_ALL
LC_COLLATE
LC_CTYPE
LC_IDENTIFICATION
LC_MEASUREMENT
LC_MESSAGES
LC_MONETARY
LC_NAME
LC_NUMERIC
LC_PAPER
LC_TELEPHONE
LC_TIME
```

`LANG` defines the value to be used for each non-explicitly defined `LC_*` variable; so if none of the `LC_*` variables is currently defined in your shell's environment (that is the default behavior, if `env | grep '^LC_'` doesn't output anything it means that's the case) and you wish to set the value of all the categories to `en_US.UTF-8`, simply export `LANG`:

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Otherwise you'll have to either also override each previously defined `LC_*` variable or (alternatively, more easily) just export `LC_ALL`, which overrides any previously defined `LC_*` variable:

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

However programs using GNU gettext will rely on `LANGUAGE` rather than `LANG` / `LC_ALL` (unless `LANG` / `LC_ALL` is set to `C`) and will set the language based on its content. `LANGUAGE` should define a list of colon-separated languages. If a translation for the first colon-separated language listed is not available, the program will try to use to the second colon-separated language listed etc; for example, to set English as the preferred language and Greek as a fallback language:

```
export LANGUAGE=en:el
```

So in your case, since you want to set everything to English (assuming that programs using GNU gettext should use Greek as a fallback language):

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en:el
```

Or if some `LC_*` variables are defined already in your shell's environment and you wish to override them:

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en:el
```

To make the settings stick, add the `export`s at the end of `~/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 0):

Question was: "How do I change the language of the terminal to English?".

Put

```
LANG=C
```

or

```
LANG=C.UTF-8
```

(the world has turned ... UTF8 became common)   into

```
.bashrc
```

or

```
/etc/bash.bashrc
```

After reboot it works for terminals.
Does not affect GUI.

If language setting shall apply to remote (SSH) login use

```
.profile
```

or

```
/etc/profile
```

That's all. Other locations may apply!