# Can I change the language of command line output without changing locale in general?

Tags: command-line, language-support, bashrc

I want to change my language for the command line only. There are [similar](https://askubuntu.com/q/741806/338446) [questions](https://askubuntu.com/q/638186/338446) already, but I didn't understand their answers. In `~/.bashrc`, I tried to add either `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8`, `export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` or `echo 'export LANG=en_US.UTF-8' >>~/.bashrc`, but the command line still speak Czech as my Ubuntu in general.

What did I miss? Does it need to be inserted in a special position (now it's almost in the beginning)? Do I need another command? Do I need to write it somewhere else?

Comment: I'm Italian, and the outputs of my commands were in Italian. Some months ago I put `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8` at the very end of `~/.bashrc`, then I ran `source ~/.bashrc` in the terminal (or simply closed and opened it). From that moment, my outputs are in English. This does not change the language of the Terminal app or the language of your system, it does change only the language of the commands output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `LANGUAGE` too, i.e. in `~/.bashrc`:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
unset LANGUAGE
```